# Is there a synchronous version of child_process.fork() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, child-process

There is `spawn` and `spawnSync`, but there is no `forkSync` for `fork`. Or did I fail to find it? If not, why is there no `forkSync`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fork` is *only* synchronous, returning `ChildProcess`. There is no callback involved, nor a promise to be fulfilled.

(i.e. There is no `child_process.forkSync` for the same reason there is no `console.logSync`)

EDIT: In comparison to `spawn` and `spawnSync` - the purpose of `spawnSync` is to wait till the child process is done, not just to launch it. The sole difference between `fork` and `spawn` is the existence of a communication channel between the parent and the child process, which is useless if the parent is frozen in time. Thus, `forkSync` in that context would make no sense (as different than `spawnSync`).

Comment: But there is no callback involved in `spawn` is it?

Comment: It would be nice for it to wait for the IPC channel to be open. Now you need to handle that yourself before you try to use it.

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev Yes there is no callback involved in `spawn` too. `Fork` is almost same as `Spawn` but it adds a communication channel between Parent and child process using `process.send()`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `forkSync()` but you can do the following to execute the child process and wait for it to exit:

```
async function fork(scriptPath, args = []) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let process = childProcess.fork(scriptPath, args, {
                    cwd: path.dirname(scriptPath)
                });
    
                process.on('exit', code => resolve(code));
                process.on('error', err => reject(err));
            });
}
```

To run it you can use it like so:

```
async run() {
    await fork('../../somescript/index.js', ['arg1', 'arg2']);
    // or
    await fork('../../somescript/index.js');
}
```

This function also has the advantage that it runs the script with the current working directory in the script directory, so if you have config files near the script itself or use relative paths it work correctly.